# GWT compile error , a pop up comes up in eclipse neon

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

**exception stack trace**

java.lang.NullPointerException  at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.launch.GWTLaunchConfiguration.maybeGetDevJarPath(GWTLaunchConfiguration.java:170)    at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.launch.GWTLaunchConfiguration.computeDynamicVMArgs(GWTLaunchConfiguration.java:114)  at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.launch.GWTLaunchConfiguration.computeCompileDynamicVMArgsAsList(GWTLaunchConfiguration.java:41)  at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.compile.GWTCompileRunner.computeCompilerCommandLine(GWTCompileRunner.java:223)   at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.compile.GWTCompileRunner.compile(GWTCompileRunner.java:81)   at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.compile.GWTCompileRunner.compileWithCancellationSupport(GWTCompileRunner.java:126)   at com.google.gwt.eclipse.core.actions.GWTCompileToolbarHandler$1.runInWorkspace(GWTCompileToolbarHandler.java:136)     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

**session data**

eclipse.buildId=4.6.2.M20161124-1400 java.version=1.8.0_121 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -data file:/C:/WorkSpace_4.2.200/ -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the Eclipse plugin. I think to fix this, setup a GWT sdk in the preferences, and it should fix it.

https://github.com/gwt-plugins/gwt-eclipse-plugin/blob/46be0237fd1255cc76056889a64d4c9f04910b1f/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.core/src/com/google/gwt/eclipse/core/launch/GWTLaunchConfiguration.java

Comment: can u explain me in details, i couldn't solve the fix using the link u provided.

Comment: Go to the Eclipse preferences, then to GWT, and find the GWT Settings. There should be some SDKs listed, add at least one GWT sdk, such as GWT 2.7.0. https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/5977216d66a2bcf953fe935fd4f3b115

Comment: yes i did this, it didn't solve my problem.  i am getting error  **"An internal error occurred during: "InboundPatientAccessErrorFilterGwt - GWT Compile".
java.lang.NullPointerException"**